# Keeping String format while sending it to a printer

Tags: java

I am new to this forum. Does anyone know how to keep a string format while sending to a printer like microsoft xps printer? My code is below:

```
String uniPQtyToPFormat = "%1$-20s%5s%25s\r\n";
String unitPrice="1000.00x";
String numberOfUnits="1.00";
String totalPrice="10000000.00";
String formattedUniPQtyToP=String.format(uniPQtyToPFormat,unitPrice,StringUtils.center(numberOfUnits,10),totalPrice);
```

When I print the **formattedUniPQtyToP** line in a text file, the format is well preserved as I expect. This appears in the text file as:

```
1000.00x                   1000.00x                      10000000.00
```

However, when I print **formattedUniPQtyToP**, total price goes to the next line instead of staying at the same line as unitPrice and numberOfUnits as it is illustrated below:

```
1000.00x                   1000.00x              
10000000.00
```

To print the string to xps printer, I am using the following code:

```
while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
    int next=measurer.nextOffset(wrappingWidth);
    int limit=next;
    if(limit<=text.length()){
        for(int i=measurer.getPosition();i<next;i++){
            char c=text.charAt(i);
            if(c=='\n'){//to break text into line in case there are many lines
                limit=i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth,limit,false);
    pen.y += layout.getAscent();
    float dx = layout.isLeftToRight() ? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
    layout.draw(graphics2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
    pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
}
```

I welcome any help or hint.
Patrick

Comment: Are you sure that long final string *plus* its preceding spaces would actually fit on a single line? Unfamiliar with the printing commands, but your code seems to be measuring each next 'word' to make sure it fits on the page. Add tracing code so you know *why* it thinks there should be a new line.

Comment: Xaver Kapeller, when I increase the width of the document and try to print many lines, the text is not justified as I get it in a text file.